# jQuery - keeping count and updating id's of dynamically added/removed elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I want to do is when I remove an element in the middle of the count, it updates and keeps count of the id's so that it would not have skipped numbered id's.

I'm doing a form builder or a customized form that would add for example a radio group without limit.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var counter = 1;
    $("#addButton").click(function () {

        var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
            .attr("id", 'KpiDiv' + counter);
        newTextBoxDiv.append(
            '<div id="radio">'
        '<label>Performance Criteria #' + counter + ': </label>' +
        '<input type="textbox"' +
        ' id="RadioLabel" value="" name=' + counter + ' ><p></p>' +
        '<label for="radios">Score</label>' +
        '<label class="radio-inline" for="radios-0">' +
        '<input type = "radio" name = "radios" id = "kpi' + counter + '-radios-0" value = "1" checked = "checked" > 1' +
        '</label>' +
        '<label class="radio-inline" for="radios-0">' +
        '<input type = "radio" name = "radios" id = "kpi' + counter + '-radios-0" value = "2" checked = "checked" > 2' +
        '</label>' +
        '<label class="radio-inline" for="radios-0">' +
        '<input type = "radio" name = "radios" id = "kpi' + counter + '-radios-0" value = "3" checked = "checked" > 3' +
        '</label>' +
        '<label class="radio-inline" for="radios-0">' +
        '<input type = "radio" name = "radios" id = "kpi' + counter + '-radios-0" value = "4" checked = "checked" > 4' +
        '</label>' +
        '<label class="radio-inline" for="radios-0">' +
        '<input type = "radio" name = "radios" id = "kpi' + counter + '-radios-0" value = "5" checked = "checked" > 5' +
        '</label>' +
        '</div>'
        );
        newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#FormGroup");
        counter++;
    });

    $("#removeButton").click(function () {
        if (counter == 1) {
            alert("Nothing more to remove");
            return false;
        }

        counter--;
        $("#RadioBoxDiv" + counter).remove();
    });
```

Comment: you've described what you want to do. But...there's a lot of code there. What is it currently doing? What have you debugged so far? Where precisely in that code are you seeing a problem?

Comment: Please read this: [mcve]

Comment: you have to create a very simple and minimal example of the problem, and I mean ~15% of the code you've shown here will suffice, with acquitted explanation.

Comment: What is doing is when I click a button it adds this html which adds a radio group. What I want is when I add 3 radio groups and I want to delete the 2nd one which is in the middle, I want to keep count of the id's.